# Folder 1new created during Joomla update

Tags: joomla-3.x, update, configuration, global-configuration, logs

I recently updated my Joomla installation and noticed that the installer created folder named 1new on the server. Folder contains two subfolders; tmp and logs. Logs folder contains two files joomla_update.php and error.php.
Both files contains only some log information but error.php contains unsuccesfully login attempts too.

```
#
#<?php die('Forbidden.'); ?>
#Date: 2017-01-23 20:33:34 UTC
#Software: Joomla Platform 13.1.0 Stable [ Curiosity ] 24-Apr-2013 00:00 GMT

#Fields: datetime   priority clientip   category    message
2017-01-23T20:33:34+00:00   INFO **.**.**.**    joomlafailure   Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet.
```

What is the meaning of that folder and those logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure this folder was created with the update?

What it looks to me is that your joomla is configured to have its `tmp` and `logs` directories inside this `1new` folder, like so: `1new/logs` & `1new/tmp`.

So review your configuration and see what is the value of the tmp and logs path.

You can check it either from the **global configuration** in the backend, or directly in the `configuration.php`- in the last case look for the `$log_path` & `$tmp_path` variables.